# Replacement of "IN" in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have huge store procedure.  I only paste small part of this.

My Query:

```
--declare variable and Select Statement goes here
WHERE  ((v.[RoleID] IN (
         SELECT [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles].roleid 
         FROM [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] 
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[aspnet_Users] 
           ON [dbo].[aspnet_Users].userid = [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles].userid 
         WHERE 
           [dbo].[aspnet_Users].username = @UserName 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT [RoleId] 
         FROM   dbo.aspnet_roles 
         WHERE loweredrolename = 'anonymous user') 
OR v.username = @UserName))
```

Query works perfect  but its take long time to execute. There is so many condition inside `WHERE` condition with `IN`. *I think* the subquery inside `IN` take time. Is there any way to optimize this query and  replace `IN` inside `WHERE` condition. Or suggest me an alternative way to optimize this type of query. Thanks.

Comment: You can try replacing the `IN` with `EXISTS`. Should quicken the execution if there are lots of records in the tables.

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense to me. Why a union with a roleid in aspnet_roles?

Comment: As far as you are inside a stored procedure, you might preselect into a #temptable and joining this.

Comment: You *think* that the cost is in this subquery? How about generating an execution plan and actually finding out where the costs are. And see whether the server is suggesting any missing indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Since the output of inner subquery is always the same. You can take that outside and   insert those values into a temptable like below and u could just query to the temp table. So each time it doesnt go in a loop executing the same

```
  `create table #temp(roleid int); `

  ` insert into #temp as (sSELECT [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles].roleid 
     FROM [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] 
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[aspnet_Users] 
       ON [dbo].[aspnet_Users].userid = [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles].userid 
     WHERE 
       [dbo].[aspnet_Users].username = @UserName 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT [RoleId] 
     FROM   dbo.aspnet_roles 
     WHERE loweredrolename = 'anonymous user');`

    WHERE  ((v.[RoleID] IN ( select roleid from #temp);
```

Comment: "So each time it doesnt go in a loop executing the same" - what makes you think it would perform a loop and repeatedly execute the query? It may, or it may not. It may already effectively perform what you're suggesting (by using a spool operator). Without seeing the execution plan for the query, we don't know what it's doing or where the actual costs lie.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a temp table with the result of the IN clause and join to it. This would break the problem to two much simpler tasks.

Answer (score -2):

according to  Orangecrush recommendation

```
--declare variable and Select Statement goes here
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] 
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[aspnet_Users] 
           ON [dbo].[aspnet_Users].userid = [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles].userid 
         WHERE 
           [dbo].[aspnet_Users].username = @UserName 
             AND [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles].roleid = v.[RoleID]
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT 1
         FROM   dbo.aspnet_roles 
         WHERE loweredrolename = 'anonymous user'
           AND dbo.aspnet_roles.roleid = v.[RoleID])
OR v.username = @UserName)
```

Comment: OK;)Why not? Explain please